# Tracking Guild Names and Guild Ids In Embeds

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have this code:

```
  logging_channel=client.get_channel(776924690291097621)
  embed = discord.Embed(
    title = 'Command Used',
    description = f"""
    User's Id: {ctx.author.id}
    User's Name: {ctx.author.name}
    Command: !help
    Guild Name: {discord.Message.guild}
    Guild Id: {discord.Message.guild_id} """,
    colour = discord.Colour.purple()
    )
  embed.set_footer(text = "Support Server")
  embed.set_author(name = "") 
  await logging_channel.send(embed=embed)
```

It's supposed to send an embed with the author id, author name, command, guild name, and guild_id. However, when I run this, I get this error:

```
Command raised an exception: AttributeError: type object 'Message' has no attribute 'guild_id'
```

When I remove the 'discord.Message.guild_id' part, it just sends:

Guild: <discord.utils.CachedSlotProperty object at 0x7fbea504e430>
as part of the embed.

How do I fix this, and what does the error mean?

Comment: If you removed guild_id it is returning info correlating to Message.  What keys exist under Message?  When looking up the api https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#message you can see you would want to sauy:    `discord.Message.guild.id`.  I think that guild object might may leverage a __str__ function to have it display the name?

Answer (score 0):

You can access to the guild `name` and `id` with your [`Context`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=context#discord.ext.commands.Context) object since it has a [`guild`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=context#discord.ext.commands.Context.guild) attribute :

```py
logging_channel=client.get_channel(776924690291097621)
embed = discord.Embed(
    title = 'Command Used',
    description = f"""
    User's Id: {ctx.author.id}
    User's Name: {ctx.author.name}
    Command: !help
    Guild Name: {ctx.guild.name}
    Guild Id: {ctx.guild.id} """,
    colour = discord.Colour.purple()
)
embed.set_footer(text = "Support Server")
embed.set_author(name = "") 
await logging_channel.send(embed=embed)
```

What you were doing instead is creating a blank `discord.Message` and since `discord.Message` objects don't have any `guild_id` attribute, you have this error.